# ¿Cómo puedo concatenar las posiciones de un array en otra función?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Tengo el siguiente código hecho en Codeignater:

```
public function ListarCompromisos4(){

    $data['filas'] = '';
    $data['num_compromiso'] = 0;

    $data['compromisos_4'] = $this->M_compromisos->listar_compromisos4();
    //echo json_encode( $objetos_compromisos = $data['compromisos_4']);
    $objetos_compromisos = $data['compromisos_4'];
    $colors = array('#00A36A', '#212743', '#694688', '#6CBB37');
    foreach ($objetos_compromisos as $datos) {
        foreach ($colors as $color) {
            $data['filas'] .= $this->fila_compromiso($datos['iIdCompromiso'], $datos['vCompromiso'], $datos['iNumero'],$color);

            $data['num_compromiso']++;
        }

    }
}
public function fila_compromiso($iIdCompromiso, $nombre, $numero,$color)
{

    $html = ' <div class="col-lg-3 featured-box-full featured-box-full-primary" style="background-color: '.$color.'">
            <a href="#">
                <h1><strong>'.$numero.'</strong></h1>
                <h4><strong>Compromiso</strong></h4>
                <h4 class="font-weight-light" style="text-align: center">'.$nombre.'</h4>
            </a>
        </div>';

    echo $html;

}
```

Lo que yo quiero obtener es algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, el código anterior genera algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si solo hago un foreach al arreglo `$datos`, obtengo una sola fila con datos pero son del mismo color, lo que necesito es que al momento de crear los elementos, me los cree con diferentes colores como se muestra en la primera imagen. Cree un arreglo llamado `$colors`, por eso tengo dos `foreach`, sin embargo al hacer eso me genera varias filas pero si con los colores diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que hay mas de un elemento para cada tipo de compromiso. Una solución puede ser consolidar los elementos del mismo tipo de compromiso para cada uno de estos.

Intentando respetar al  máximo tu código, te presento un ejemplo:

```
/* 
Establecemos una estructura de datos para almacenar el consolidado de los tipos de compromisos en un array asociativo donde cada elemento es a su vez un arreglo con info
de cada compromiso, incluyendo los colores respectivos

Fijate que a los subindices asociativos los he llamado "iIdCompromiso-N", reemplaza eso por el id de tus compromisos
*/

$compromisosConsolidados = array(
    "iIdCompromiso-1" => array(
        "iNumero"     => 0,
        "vCompromiso" => "",
        "color"       => "#00A36A"
    ),
    "iIdCompromiso-2" => array(
        "iNumero"     => 0,
        "vCompromiso" => "",
        "color"       => "#212743"
    ),
    "iIdCompromiso-3" => array(
        "iNumero"     => 0,
        "vCompromiso" => "",
        "color"       => "#6946882"
    ),
    "iIdCompromiso-4" => array(
        "iNumero"     => 0,
        "vCompromiso" => "",
        "color"       => "#6CBB37"
    )
);


/*
Recorremos los compromisos y vamos almacenando en $compromisosConsolidados
la suma de sus apariciones, y preparamos los textos de cada compromiso dentro de un elemento <li>
*/

foreach ($objetos_compromisos  as $datos) {
    $iIdCompromiso = datos["iIdCompromiso"];
    $compromisosConsolidados[ $iIdCompromiso ]["iNumero"]     += $datos["iNumero"];
    $compromisosConsolidados[ $iIdCompromiso ]["vCompromiso"] .= "<li> <span class='font-weight-light' style='text-align: center'>" . $datos["vCompromiso"] . "</span></li>";
}


/*
Finalmente, construimos el html que desplegará el contenido generado recorriendo a $compromisosConsolidados 
*/

$html = "";
foreach ($compromisosConsolidados as $idConsolidado=>$consolidado) {
    $html .= fila_compromiso(
        $idConsolidado, 
        $consolidado["vCompromiso"], 
        $consolidado["iNumero"], 
        $cosolidado["color"]
    );
}

echo $html;


/*
¿Recuerdas que pusimos los textos de los compromisos dentro de un elemento <li>? Pues bien, si te fijas, en fila_compromiso(), reemplazamos el <h4> por un elemento <ul>
*/
public function fila_compromiso($iIdCompromiso, $nombre, $numero,$color)
{

    $html = '<div class="col-lg-3 featured-box-full featured-box-full-primary" style="background-color: '.$color.'">
       <a href="#">
           <h1><strong>'.$numero.'</strong></h1>
           <h4><strong>Compromiso</strong></h4>
           <ul>'.$nombre.'</ul>
       </a>
    </div>';

    return $html;
}
```

Existen mejores y mas elegantes formas de resolver este problema, pero esta me gusta porque es fácil de seguir y entender, aunque quizas un poco extensa.

Finalmente, como sugerencia, te aconsejo leer exhaustivamente la fuente autorizada sobre arrays en PHP, [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.array.php) y [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php).

¡Mucha suerte!

Comment: Si claro, entendí tu idea y si es un tanto extensa, pude plantear la lógica del algoritmo de distinta manera y la manera en como lo resolví fue mentiendo un contador dentro del `foreach` y concatenarle el valor del color dependiendo de la posición, ¡muchas gracias por la ayuda!